# How to consistently break out of { when typing interactively in R

Tags: r

When typing interactively, if you realize you've made a mistake and want to break out of the braced expression without executing it, what's the best way to do it?

I usually just do something like this (type random characters), which works.  I seem to recall it not working a few times, though.  For instance, I'll often type a closed parens `)`, which doesn't break out of the braced expression if I've already typed an open parens somewhere.

```
> if(TRUE) {
+ !@##!@#
Error: unexpected '@' in:
"if(TRUE) {
!@"
```

Or if you've typed a quote then the above doesn't work:

```
> if(TRUE) {
+ "
+ !@##!@#
+
```

So the question is this:

> Without having to evaluate what has been typed on previous lines, how can you break out of the endless sequence of "give me more input" `+` prompts?

Or stated differently, given,

```
if(TRUE) {
...
+
```

what expression breaks evaluation for all possible `...`'s?

Comment: (I tested in a non-Gui mode and the `esc` does not work but the linked question has an answer for those using a naked-console interface.)

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+C? This works for most REPLs I've used.

Comment: ctrl-c does not work in some gui's, but ctrl-c followed by `esc` would be fairly general exit-to-top strategy.

Comment: I'm on a mac, and for me it's `CTRL+C`  (not `CMD`) in both the R GUI and in terminal.  I also use `RStudio` hosted on an amazon box, and there it is `esc`

Comment: There is a posting to r-help today that warns people with a Java interface that ctrl-c may abort Java and crash R.

Comment: I'd tried CTRL-C before but never with escape.  Thanks. @DWin Noted.  Fortunately I don't use a Java-based interface.